# ServiceObjectPropertyException on task,IsReminderSet and task.ReminderDueDate

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am binding a task in ews.

In Microsoft docs it says:

"Binds to an existing task and loads its first class properties."

Due to the List of First Class Properties IsReminderSet is a first class property in task.

Still that property returns an

"ServiceObjectPropertyException was unhandeld:

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

```
ews.Task task = ews.Task.Bind(service, ID);
if (task.IsReminderSet)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a start make sure you using the latest version of library from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api. The other thing you can do is enable tracing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/05/03/ews-best-practices-tracing-and-logging/ this will allow you to see exactly what the server is actually sending back to. Its possible especially if mailboxes has been migrated that these properties can be null on the server side (due to the migration method used).